# Query mongoose multiple models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing a little app with the **MEAN stack** and I'm having trouble to query my models.

I have 4 models, in separate files.

Here's the Invoice model :

```
var invoiceSchema = new Schema ({
    employee : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employee' },
    customer : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer' },
    products : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
    priced : Number,
    qty : Number,
    comment : String,
    date : Date
});

var Invoice = mongoose.model('Invoice',invoiceSchema);

exports.createInv = function (req, res) {
    Invoice.create({
        employee : req.body.employee,
        customer : req.body.customer,
        products  : req.body.products,
        priced : req.body.priced,
        qty : req.body.qty,
        comment : req.body.comment,
        date : req.body.date
    }, function(err) {
        if (err)
            return res.send(err);
    });
}
```

As you can see it points to the 3 others models for the 3 first fields.
So far all is working, I'm able to populate an invoice with the data coming from Employee, Product and Customer.

But I'm quite lost for doing that :

I'd like to have for each Employee, the total of their sales (when they create an invoice, qty * price).

How to Increment the **totalSales** field in the **Employee Model** for each **Invoice** creation ?

Employee Model :

```
var employeeSchema = new Schema ({
    firstname : String,
    lastname : {type : String, unique : true},
    age : Number,
    dept : String,
    mail : String,
    phone : String,
    totalsales : Number
});
var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee',employeeSchema);
```

I use a Service with $http to post datas.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems kind of straight forward. But I'm guessing that the example below is what you're looking for.

```
exports.createInv = function (req, res) {
    Invoice.create({
        employee : req.body.employee,
        customer : req.body.customer,
        products  : req.body.products,
        priced : req.body.priced,
        qty : req.body.qty,
        comment : req.body.comment,
        date : req.body.date
    }, function(err) {
        if (err)
            return res.send(err);
    });

   Employee.findOne({"_id":req.body.employee}, function (err, doc) {
      var salesPrice = req.body.priced * req.body.qty;
      doc.totalSales += salesPrice;
      doc.save();
   })
}
```

You probably want to add validation to make sure that your invoice got created. And also add a callback to the save-method.

Comment: Great, but I need to "references" the Employee Model I guess, as it produce an error TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'findById' (for the line Employee.findById). As my models are in separate files I don't know how to do that, and I would like to avoid RequireJS just for this need. Anyway thank you for this answer !

Comment: That's strange. You can try the findOne then. I'll update my example.